# Cleaning build chromium

Tags: build, chromium, ninja

I compile chromium on WIN according to the instructions (https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/build-instructions-windows)

The output ("out/Release") get a very large folder (20gb)
After `ninja -t clean` the folder size is reduced to 8gb

Is it possible to get just binaries?
Or need selected manually, if so what are the files needed for chromium?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but in my opinion, those files which you aforementioned were used for decreasing building time in next time when you modify some code and rebuild.

When you modify one source file and build project again, it just needs to rebuild some relating files and modules, not whole project at the beginning. It will save your time considerably.